# Android Studio Gradle Sync Toggles which classes are included

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Does anyone know why Syncing Gradle in Android Studio would cause some classes to be un-included? Every time I do a Gradle Sync, it toggles which classes are recognized:
[image: Android Studio Gradle Sync cycles]

Here are the dependencies from my build.gradle file:

```html
dependencies {

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.9.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.9.0'
    compile group: 'org.jgrapht', name: 'jgrapht-ext', version:'1.1.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    compile 'ttr.shared:ticket-to-ride-shared:6.8'
}
```

Comment: Update: I can reproduce the bug. The ttr.shared package is a Maven java publication. The bug occurs when I run `gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` for a ttr.shared package version that has been used before. It goes away if I include a ttr.shared package version that has never been used before.